# Single or simple?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here's a [comprehension question](http://ilielearning-sd.ir/content/lessons/13/Intermediate3_2/unit_2/reading/exercise/r3.swf) for a reading:

> According to the passage, when you have a **single** headache, _______ .
>   a. use natural headache remedies  ✓
>   b. see a doctor
>   c. rush to your medicine cabinet
>   d. try different kinds of pain relievers

And here's the [passage](http://media.open.edu.cn/media_file/netcourse/asx/zhyy3/unit/unit9/kwyy/menu.htm).
I wonder what `single headache` means. Is `simple` mistyped as `single`? Could it refer to a single headache episode as opposed to a recurrent headache problem?

Comment: I cannot find the word "single" in that text. It does sound like "if you have a single episode" as opposed to _Always see a doctor for continuous or recurring head pain._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term is referring to a single instance of a headache as opposed to recurring headaches (you've had a headache every day for two weeks, say). In other words, you rarely get headaches but today you have one. The expectation is that this one will go away in a while without intervention, but right now you wish to make it go away more quickly.